# CSP: Why are 'none' and 'unsafe-inline' being interpreted as hostnames?

Tags: python, security, flask, content-security-policy

I'm fairly new to CSP, and I'm trying to use Talisman on a Flask site... complicated by Adobe Fonts, which seems to be CSP-averse. That said, the site works, loads the Adobe Fonts, and so on.

However, the Web Console is showing the following message:

```sh
Content Security Policy: Interpreting unsafe-inline as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use ‘unsafe-inline’ (wrapped in single quotes).
Content Security Policy: Interpreting none as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use ‘none’ (wrapped in single quotes).
```

And my CSP looks like this:

```py
SELF = "'self'"

csp = {
    'default-src': SELF,
    'script-src': [
        SELF,
        'use.typekit.net',
        'cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js',
    ],
    'style-src': [SELF, 'unsafe-inline', 'use.typekit.net'],
    'font-src': [SELF, 'use.typekit.net'],
    'img-src': [SELF, 'p.typekit.net'],
    'object-src': 'none',
}

app = Flask(__name__)
talisman = Talisman(app, content_security_policy=csp)
```

Like I said, it *works*, but these errors are troubling. I've tried every combination of single quotes, double quotes, no quotes... Nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is [an example on the project home page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman#example-2):

```
csp = {
    'default-src': [
        '\'self\'',
        '*.trusted.com'
    ]
}
```

`none` can be added in the same way.